# Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.MockingFrameworkReporterFactoryImpl

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to write a unit test using PowerMockRunner but I got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error:
>   org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.MockingFrameworkReporterFactoryImpl
>   could not be located in classpath.    at
>   org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getFrameworkReporterFactory(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:190)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

I've checked all the dependencies and it's ok, do I need somehthing else?

Answer (score 24):

After posting the question I found the answer, it seems to be a problem with version 1.6.5, it needs an additional dependency, it's described [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/FAQ).

The dependency is powermock-api-mockito-common version 1.6.5, you can either add it to you pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>     
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

or download the [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/powermock/powermock-api-mockito-common/1.6.5/powermock-api-mockito-common-1.6.5.jar)

Comment: Can someone post a zip file that contains the JAR? This solution should fix this issue.

Answer (score 6):

After adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>     
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

we are getting - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in class path."

To resolve this issue add below dependency as well -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

now its working fine

Answer (score 5):

Following these - http://fewtechissues.blogspot.com/2017/12/mockito-error.html dependencies and versions fixed the issue for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```